# Hashing Passwords for login form in SQL Server VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms, hashcode

I have a login form in VB.NET that requires a username and password input. If the user inputs match the correct login details in the SQL Server DB then another VB form is shown.

The password needs to be hashed, without using MD5.

```
    Dim Bytes() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(txtPassword.Text)
    Dim HashofBytes() As Byte = New System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Managed().ComputeHash(bytes)
    Dim StrHash As String = Convert.ToBase64String(HashofBytes)

    Using con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=""G:\Program\X\Database1.mdf"";Integrated Security=True")

        con.Open()

        Dim query As String = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE Username=@Username AND Password=@Password"
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(query, con)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Username", txtUsername.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Password", StrHash))

        Try

            If cmd.ExecuteScalar() = 1 Then

                frmOverview.ShowDialog()

                Me.Hide()

            Else

                MsgBox("You have entered an invalid username or password")

            End If

        Catch ex As SqlException
            MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString())
        End Try

    End Using

    txtPassword.Clear()
```

However, the issue I have is that even if the user inputs the correct login details the next form is not shown. How could this be resolved?

Comment: MDF?  I suspect you mean MD5.  SHA is not the way to go for hashing passowrds.  I suggest you get `BCrypt`, it is extremely simple to use.  The rest is a debugging issue but `@Password` will always equal `@Password`

Comment: Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `PBKDF2` (aka `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`), `password_hash`/`password_verify`, `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force. Protecting your users is important, please use secure password methods.

Comment: Why are you calling `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` twice?

Comment: I made a video about encrypting a database and accessing it from vb https://youtu.be/AwdqK2w1sjc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Plutonix said, check your Password where clause:

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE Username=@Username AND @Password=@Password`

it should be:

`...AND Password=@Password`